# Dynamically Changing Min Max Values of Slider

Tags: jquery-mobile

Trying to change the min and Max value of the Slider defined in Html Code

```
     <input type="range"  id="slider" min="0" max="100" value="50" />
```

at runtime like the following :

```
$( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "min", 40 );
$( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "max", 90 );
```

But its not working, Kindly help . No error . Also tried destroy() and refresh() , but no change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.prop()` to change `min` and `max` and then `.slider("refresh")` to apply changes.

```
$("#slider").prop({
  min: 40,
  max: 90
}).slider("refresh");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/tg2cf/)**

Comment: It works , Thanks @Omar ! Don't we use values to update the value as well ?

Comment: to update value `$("#slider").val(60).slider("refresh");`. @Learner

Comment: Can't we do it in the same prop() by mentioning one more field ?

Comment: Ohhk @Omar , thatworks Great ! I was trying Values and Val instead of Value . Thanks :)